# Working with R and .C to return dot product

Tags: c++, r

I am trying to return the inner product of two vectors in .C with R. After this I want the function to return true if the inner product is equal to zero and false otherwise.
I have written a small .cpp function that calculates the inner product correct.
When I have a vector of length 2 
e.g a <- c(5,-5)
    b <- c(5,5)

this returns 0 as the result and true as the result is equal to zero.

However when I increase the length of the vector in the R calling code
e.g a <- c(5,-5,4)
    b <- c(5,5,4)

It returns 16 as the result which is fine but it returns true which is incorrect
as the result is not equal to zero.

Can anybody help understand what I am doing wrong here?

The code is below for .C

```
#include <R.h>
extern "C" {
    void test(int * x1, int * x2, int * len, int * result, bool * tf)
    {
        int n = *len;
        *result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            *result = *result + x1[i] * x2[i];
            if (*result == 0)
            {
                *tf = TRUE;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have changed this to the code

```
#include <R.h>

extern "C" {

  void test (int * x1, int * x2, int * len, int * result, int * tf)
 // void test (int * x1, int * x2, int * result)
  {
    int n = *len ;
      *result = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
         *result += x1[i] * x2[i]; 
      *tf = *result == 0;
    }
  }
```

and when i use R to call this as below

```
a <- c(-5,5,4)
b <- c(5,5,3)
len <- length(a)
c <- 0
ans <- FALSE

.C("test", x1 = as.integer(a), x2 = as.integer(b), 
   len = as.integer(length(a)),
   result = as.integer(c),
   tf = as.logical(ans))
```

The output is

```
$x1
[1] -5  5  4

$x2
[1] 5 5 3

$len
[1] 3

$result
[1] 12

$tf
[1] TRUE
```

Since Result is not 0 tf should be FALSE and it is when the vector is of length 1 or 2. Only when I increase it to length 3 or more does this happen. Can anyone help please?

Comment: you did not set *tf to FALSE. btw, I don't see tf defined anywhere.

Comment: What is 'tf'? It's not declared anywhere.I assume its the return value of the function (also not shown) and if so, the previous comment applies. Also, I think you want to check if (*result == 0) **after** the for loop has finished, not during it's execution.

Comment: @user2867342 yes it is, it is passed to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is buggy. Here is the fixed version:

```
#include <R.h>
extern "C" {
   void isOrthn (int * x1, int * x2, int * len, int * result, bool * tf)
   {
      int n = *len ;
      *result = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
         *result += x1[i] * x2[i]; 
      *tf = *result == 0;
   }   
}
```

Basically, you could get out without ever initializing tf. By moving the test outside the loop, it is simpler, cleaner and one clearly sees that *tf's value is functionally dependent on the result being 0.

Comment: Might be the way you marshall the arguments in and out of R. The C code above is correct though.Take a look a the type of your last argument (bool) that might be an issue with R.

Comment: Thanks. When I use R to call this function it does not return the correct answer for tf though except when the vector is only of length 2? I will look at the type of the last argument.

Comment: I added in the R code in an edit as with your amendment it is still not returning as I would expect?

Comment: I just tested on my machine: Saved the C code in a file test.cpp. Then, ran R CMD SHLIB test.cpp and ran R at the command line. It worked as expected, the result is toggling between true and false as expected. Did you recompile the .so file from the cpp? Did you reload it in R?

Comment: I placed curly brackets after the *result line for the *tf = *result ==0; line and it works then! thanks

Answer (score 2):

Briefly:

- Do not use `.C()`, its use is discouraged in all new code (cf discussions on r-devel in the last few years).
- Your code has a logic error in that it does not compute the full inner product before testing: complete the loop

Below is how I would write this in RcppArmadillo:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
bool checkInner(const arma::vec a, const arma::vec b) {
  double ip = arma::as_scalar(a.t() * b);
  return ip == 0.0;
}

/*** R
checkInner( c(1,2), c(-2,1))
checkInner( 1:3, 2:4 )
*/
```

We just `sourceCpp(...)` the file, and it is compiled, linked, loaded and the R code at the bottom is run as well:

```
R> sourceCpp("/tmp/inner.cpp")

R> checkInner( c(1,2), c(-2,1))
[1] TRUE

R> checkInner( 1:3, 2:4 )
[1] FALSE
R>
```